# How do I implement a function to generate perfect numbers using java functional interface?

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a function that returns a list of perfect numbers up to the parameter x. I have to implement it using the java functional interface and classes that support the functional-style (stream, filter, map...).

My function should do the following

- Takes a parameter x as the limit and returns a list of perfect numbers
- In the outermost part, the code would filter a list up to x, using lambda to compare whether n is equal to the result of reducing the innermost filter (foldLeft/reducing from left)
- The innermost part has a filter with a list up to (n - 1). This filter has a lambda function that checks whether n%x == 0.

Where I am having most trouble is implementing the reduction (foldl) with the result from the innermost filter.

Here is my code:

```
    public static List<Integer> generatePerfectList(int x) {

        List<Integer> perfectList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        perfectList = IntStream.range(0, x)
                // I am also getting an error "Incompatible operand types int and OptionalInt" in the following line
                .filter(n -> (n == (IntStream.range(0, n-1).filter(x -> (0 == (n % x))).reduce(Integer::sum))))
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return perfectList;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in a lambda? It would be much more readable, testable and debuggable as a method.

Comment: I am learning Scheme at the same time, and I have been asked to make a java implementation to get perfect numbers using functional programming.

Comment: A static java method is an example of functional programming.

Comment: Interesting observation. Never thought or knew about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static List<Integer> generatePerfectList(int x) {
    return IntStream.range(1, x)
            .filter(n -> n == IntStream.range(1, n).filter(i -> 0 == n % i).sum())
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And

```
System.out.println(generatePerfectList(1000));
```

output:

```
[6, 28, 496]
```

Comment: Thanks @Saka1029. Appreciate your response!